# Getting trouble with JS variables

Tags: jquery, variables, global-variables

I've following code:

```
$("#get_details").click(function(){ 
  name = $("#user_name").val();
  var age,gender;
  $.post("users.php", { name: name },
    function(data){
      if (data.status == 'success'){
        age = data.message[0];
        gender = data.message[1];
        alert(age); //getting output
      }
    }, "json");

   alert(age);//doesn't getting output
 });
```

I want to access these values outside of `$.post()`,for this what I've to modify ?

Comment: for first click second alert doesn't working but after first click it is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the `var` defines them in the local scope. Without `var` they can be accessed from `window`, the global object (like `window.age` or `window.gender`).

But your second alert doesn't work because when it is called, the `$.post` wouldn't be completed yet, because it is asynchronous. You can do this instead:

```
$("#get_details").click(function(){

    var name = $("#user_name").val();
    var age,gender;
    var json_ready = false;

    $.post("users.php", { name: name },function(data){
        json_ready = true;
        if (!data.status == 'success') return;

        age = data.message[0];
        gender = data.message[1];
    }, "json");

    var json_alert = function(){
        if(!json_ready)  return setTimeout(function(){ json_alert(); },1000);
        alert('gender: '+gender+', age: '+age);
    }

    json_alert();

});
```

Comment: Both alerts have access to the local `age` variable; that's not the issue.

Comment: @GRIGORE-TURBODISEL how can I convert `$.post` to `$ajax`

Comment: `$.ajax({url:'', async:false, data:{name:name}, dataType:'json', type:'POST', success:function(data){ age=data.message[0]  } }); `

Comment: @GRIGORE-TURBODISEL I've used `$.ajax()` its working.Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

$.post() is asynchronous, so the second alert() is called before you get the value of age.

To make it work, you have to use $.ajax() which allows synchorous post.

Answer (score 0):

age get value on callback of $.post. and response of this callback consume time. javascript dont wait for response of $.post and immediately run alert(age).